# ASP.NET failing to load SSIS package: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, ssis

I have a ASP.NET Website which will reference a number of SSIS packages which influence an SQL database.

The first of these packages will clear all rows in a table which match an ASP NET session variable 'ID'.

The site seems to be pulling from the same SQL database okay, it just seems to be the SSIS packages which are having issues.

When I select load a package using the following syntax I get the following error:

```
    Package deletePkg = app.LoadPackage(deletePackageLocation, null);
```

**Value does not fall within the expected range**

I have quadruple checked the file path is correct.

The connection manager for this particular package seems happy when testing a connection, and is using the same configuration used multiple other times in the website. For whatever reason text and SQL logging do not seem to be working despite working in the SSIS development environment.
 (ID = ?)

After looking at numerous other discussions it has become clear that this is a pretty vague error message that can refer to any number of issues. None of which I have found have solutions fitting for my situation.

Comment: Try running a profiler trace when the package errors to see what query is being passed from the package to the database.

Comment: Did you choose the correct Data Type for the parameter in your SSIS ExecuteSQL Task?

Comment: @codemonkey I think so. It's just a String from a dropdownlist and the ExecuteSQL task uses Varchar.

Comment: My next guess would be null values in the data, or a difference in column types (null/notnull/length) between the prod en dev databases.

Comment: @codemonkey I have a debug window in my webpage to make sure the session parameter is being assigned before the package is executed. During debugging the package is pointing towards to same server and database as the live version, so the columns should be consistent.

Comment: Could you add logging to the package and report back the OnError and OnWarning events?  It would be helpful to understand which component in the package is returning this error.

Comment: Logging isn't working for what I suspect is the same issue. I have narrowed down to precisely where in the code the error is first being given; when the first package is being loaded.

Comment: Can you debug your web app locally to execute this package, rather than using debug in SSDT?  Do you get a successful execution?  Another thought, does the web app have access to the package on the server - Maybe this is a permissions issue?

Comment: The web app has full control of the folder containing to package. Does debugging locally mean deploying to the local machine? The debugging in the visual studio environment executes without issue.

Comment: What account is the ssis service running under on the server?

Comment: Looking at services the SQL Server Integration Services is logged in as NT Service\MsDtsServer110. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering if SSIS service account does not have permission to the package.  Is the package local to the server or stored on a file share?  That you can debug your application and execute the package successfully and only get this error when you run it on the server, it seems to point to a permissions issue.  Or there is something with the value of the deletePackageLocation variable i.e. pointing to a location that does not have the package on the server.  But you said you checked that already.

Comment: The package is local to the server. I've tried loading it from both a C: drive folder, as well as the inetpub folder. Here is the deletePackLocation path I have: `deletePackageLocation = @"C:\SomeFolder\SomeFolder\SSIS\Delete Items.dtsx";`

Comment: Here are the users that have permissions to the folder. Obviously I will tighten these up once the issue has been identified as it isn't very secure, but I have just been giving full control to each to rule everything out. Administrators, TrustedInstaller, IIS APPPOOL, WebAccess. Is there a means for me to add the SSIS logon user to the permission list? MsDtsServer110 doesn't seem to be a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was an unexpected issue.

deletePackageLocation was a class variable that was set on Page_load.

Although the variable was successfully set in a `if(!IsPostBack)` clause it was clearing before package loading. Once I defined the variable immediately before package loading it worked.

Very unusual solution, but it was what was preventing package loading at the end of the day.